# Integrate Jersey with RMI

Tags: java, jersey, rmi

I have a Java Jersey project, where I am running an application. On the other hand I have a project were there is a RMI application how can I put this two to work together. In other words how can I intergrate RMI/IIOP into a Jersey application.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
@Path("/items")
public class ItemsResource {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;
        Stuber s = new Stuber();


    @GET
    public Response get() throws RemoteException {
        }
```

Were I have an external class in the Jersey Project that will work as a client to connect with the RMI/IIOP

```
public class Stuber {
    Context ic;
    iRemoteLogic logic;

    public Stuber() {
        super();

        Object objref;


            try {
                ic = new InitialContext();

                objref = ic.lookup("LogicService");
                System.out.println("Client: Obtained a ref. to Hello server.");

                logic = (iRemoteLogic) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(
                        objref, iRemoteLogic.class);
```

What should I add to the Stuber class to be able to work as an RMI/IIOP client?

Thanks :)

NOTE: I followed [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi-iiop/tutorial.html) for the RMI/IIOP

Comment: Do you want to invoke your Stuber class from Jersey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to provide somewhere an implementation of `iRemoteService` that is exported via RMI/IIOP (i.e. `PortableRemoteObject`), and register it via JNDI as `LogicService`. I doubt the latter is going to work: surely you will need to provide a protocol and host to JNDI.

Comment: I have another stand alone application that does that perfectly(The PortableRemoteObject) and getting the implementation. When I copied the code to a Jersey project it stoped working. Do Jersey limits the user of doing that? Of accessing resources outside of the server?

Comment: I want the `Stuber` class to work as an RMI client, when I run the Stuber file outside of the Jersey Tomcat application it works great as a client. The problem begins when I try to integrate it to the Jersey Tomcat app, it usually get `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: @rogeliog So deploy the missing class.